# How to take a value from a table when press edit in a select?

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel

I have this div with a select

```
<div class="form-group row col-xs-4 col-md-4" >
<label class="control-label col-md-4" >Rif Holding: </label>
<div class="col-md-8">
 <select name="holdings_id" id="holdings_id" class="form-control">
    @foreach ($holdings as $holding)
      <option value="{{ $holding->holdings_id }}" name="holdings_id" id="holdings_id" class="form-control">{{ $holding->hrif }}</option>
    @endforeach
 </select>
</div>
```

when I press the button edit for edit a record in my table don't take the value in the select... I would like to see the value in the select before select another record for edit it in the select.

[image]

The select appears empty.. I would like to have the previous record that I selected for edit in the label

Comment: It is not clear what you want. Is this a JavScript issue and not at all a PHP issue, then remove all PHP and post a [mcve] using HTML and JS

Comment: I would like to obtain the value from a table in a select when I use an edit button

Comment: What is a `table in a select`??? Also options do not have names or IDs

Comment: a table with information... so when I press the button edit I will see some edit labels... In this labels I have some selects for edit... I would like to see the previous information from the table in the select before edit it

Comment: I edited my question.. sorry

Comment: `id="holdings_id"` and `name="holdings_id"` should be unique. currently, both your `select` and `option` tags have one and the same name and id.

Comment: I changed, but I dind't get the result that I want... can you explain it better?

Comment: Please post a [mcve] - we have no use of some PHP code. There is no edit button in your example. There are no tables

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution

```
<option value="{{ $holding->holdings_id }}" @if( $holding->holdings_id === $holdings_id ) selected @endif >{{ $holding->hrif }}</option>
```